# Link a location from an image

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I linked a text to a location as shown below, my problem is I don't know how to link an image this location:

```
public class PageCs extends Activity
{
    Button spw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zaza);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton()
    {
        spw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spw);

        spw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "My location";
                String latit = "00.0000000";
                String longit = "00.0000000";
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("geo:<" + latit + ">,<" + longit + ">?q=<"
                                + latit + ">,<" + longit + ">("
                                + DESTINATION_LOCATION + ")"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to link between them? what should happen after that?

Comment: The image like to the location on the map also